# Check if all the variables exist in the file at a time

Tags: shell, variables, grep, exists

Below is the do loop script to check whether a variable exists in the .sas7bdat file or not and it's working fine.But is there any way to the check that if all the variable exist in file then assign some value.

```
rword = var1 var2 var3 var4

for rwords in  $rword
   do
   cat $path | grep -i  $rwords
   if [ $? -gt  0 ];
   then
      echo "$rwords DOES NOT EXIST"
    exit
   else 
    echo "$rwords EXIST"    
   fi
 done
```

Thank you

Comment: You've got a syntax error in there so it can't be working as entered. But I think we get the gist.

Comment: @Also, your code would report *... EXIST* if the file does not contain *var1*, but instead, say, *tvar11*.

Answer (score 0):

Use `grep -q`:

## check for any of the words

```
if grep -qE -- "$var1|$var2|$var3|var4" "$path"; then
```

## check for all the words

```
if grep -q -- "$var1" "$path" && grep -q -- "$var2" "$path" && grep -q -- "$var3" "$path"; then
```

## check for a single word

```
if ! grep -q -- "$var1" "$path"; then
```

Comment: what would be the grep option or command  to check if one of the word does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Since all the variable names are unique you can do something like this:

```
if [ "$(grep --count --extended-regexp --ignore-case 'var1|var2|var3|var4' "$path")" -eq 4 ]
then
    [all variables exist]
fi
```

This, of course, is brittle in several ways:

- It would count multiple occurrences of the same variable multiple times, so if you have `var3` twice and no `var4` it would succeed wrongly.
- It would count occurrences of the variable name inside variable values, comments or other data structures in your file.
- It would count substring matches such as `var2foo`.

A better solution would be to use a library which can parse the format reliably (such as [sas7bdat](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sas7bdat)). [Bash is just bad at parsing any kind of complex file format.](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashWeaknesses)